Simple Web Server: Second Try
Based on feedback from a previous question:
Simple Web Server
This is the update.
I think I have made it simpler.
Note 1: Though the code in void handleRequest() looks like it is normal sync blocking code. Underneaths the hood the code is using boost co-routines to yield the execution of the work item when there is a blocking operation on a file descriptor. Execution will be resumed by libEvent when the file descriptor becomes available for the operation that it would have blocked on.
Note 2: When work is re-scheduled. It can be rescheduled on a completely different thread so all state of the operation must be on the stack (not in any global object).
Note 3: The concept here. Is to let users of the NisseServer to write code that works like it is normal easy to use synchronous code and use the normal std::iostream interface to read and write things to a socket (as that is as simple an interface as it gets) and an easy way to stream JSON and BSON to/from other servers.
Note 4: The output will not always be a stream (like from a file), we may have to build the result. That is why body() returns a reference to a stream that you can continue to use to send as much output as you need to and programmatically build the result on the output stream.
Things that have not been addressed yet (because they are bit more complex):

The request handler only takes a request, it returns the response.
The proliferation of deep namespace.

WebServer.cpp
#include "NisseServer/NisseServer.h"
#include "NisseServer/PyntControl.h"
#include "NisseServer/AsyncStream.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/HTTPHandler.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Request.h"
#include "NisseHTTP/Response.h"
#include <filesystem>

namespace TASock    = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket;
namespace TANS      = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::Server;
namespace TANH      = ThorsAnvil::Nisse::HTTP;
namespace FS        = std::filesystem;

class WebServer: public TANS::NisseServer
{
    TANH::HTTPHandler       http;
    TANS::PyntControl       control;
    FS::path                contentDir;

    TASock::ServerInit getServerInit(std::optional<FS::path> certPath, int port)
    {
        if (!certPath.has_value()) {
            // If there is no certPath. Then return the init object
            // used by a normal Socket.
            return TASock::ServerInfo{port};
        }

        // We have a certificate path.
        // So create the appropriate CTX object and register the certificate.
        // The return object contains the CTX and port info.
        // This will result in an SSL port being used. This allows
        // clients that are SLL aware to validate the certificate is valid.
        TASock::CertificateInfo     certificate{FS::canonical(*certPath /= "fullchain.pem"),
                                                FS::canonical(*certPath /= "privkey.pem")
                                               };
        TASock::SSLctx              ctx{TASock::SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
        return TASock::SServerInfo{port, ctx};
    }

    void handleRequest(TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response)
    {
        FS::path        requestPath = FS::path{request.variables()["path"]}.lexically_normal();
        if (requestPath.empty() || (*requestPath.begin()) == "..") {
            return response.error(400, "Invalid Request Path");
        }

        std::error_code ec;
        FS::path        filePath = FS::canonical(contentDir /= requestPath, ec);
        if (!ec && FS::is_directory(filePath)) {
            filePath = FS::canonical(filePath /= "index.html", ec);
        }
        if (ec || !FS::is_regular_file(filePath)) {
            return response.error(404, "No File Found At Path");
        }

        // Use `SocketStream` as it is async aware (unlike std::ifstream).
        // The following `async` object registers the appropriate callbacks with the server that will yield execution on a blocking read request.
        TASock::SocketStream    file{filePath.string(), TASock::FileMode::Read, TASock::Blocking::No};
        TANS::AsyncStream       async(file, request.getContext(), TANS::EventType::Read);

        response.body(TANH::Encoding::Chunked) << file.rdbuf();
    }

    public:
        WebServer(int port, FS::path& contentDir, std::optional<FS::path> certPath)
            : control(*this)
            , contentDir(contentDir)
        {
            // Any GET request passed to the http object will be handled here.
            http.addPath(TANH::Method::GET, "/{path}", [&](TANH::Request& request, TANH::Response& response){handleRequest(request, response);});

            // The http object is used to handle request on port.
            listen(getServerInit(certPath, port), http);

            // The control object is used to handle requests on `port+2`
            listen(TASock::ServerInfo{port+2}, control);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: WebServer <port> <contentDirectory> [<certificateDirectory>]\n";
        return 1;
    }
    try
    {
        int                 port        = std::stoi(argv[1]);
        FS::path            contentDir  = FS::canonical(argv[2]);
        std::optional<FS::path> certPath;
        if (argc == 4) {
            certPath = FS::canonical(argv[3]);
        }
        std::cout << "Nisse WebServer: Port: " << port << " ContentDir: >" << contentDir << "< Certificate Path: >" << (argc == 3 ? "NONE" : argv[3]) << "<\n";

        WebServer       server(port, contentDir, certPath);
        server.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        // Try catch forces the application to correctly unwind the stack.
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        // Re-throw the exception so the OS know something went wrong.
        // And does OS appropriate logging.
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: Unknown\n";
        throw;
    }
}

